Spark Job fails in EMR out of nowhere with confluent Kafka Sasl authentication exception,
The EMR job is connecting to kafka cluster to read the streaming data, it connects and the processing starts, but, sometimes randomly the job fails, with the below exception.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
Surprisingly, there is no such authentication change or any change for that matter on the confluent cluster, all the changes are planned and are prod sensitive, meaning nothing can be changed without CR.
The job resumes its normal operations if it is restarted. No idea why it fails in the first place, any idea on where the issue lies?
Spark version - 3.3
EMR version - 7.0.0
below is the code used to connect to the Kafka cluster:
    kafka_df = (
    spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", keystore_password)
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", truststore_password)
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location)
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location)
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", security_protocol)
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", sasl_mechanism)
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", sasl_jaas_config)
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers)
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
    .option("startingOffsets", offset)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "True")
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", max_offset_per_trigger)
    .load()

All the configurations are current and never changed, there is no pattern to the exception, occurs randomly.
below is the driver stacktrace:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o15557.append.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 24 in stage 6148.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 24.3 in stage 6148.0 (TID 712974) ([2600:1f14:3f59:fd00:eb79:80dc:94c3:74d5] executor 11): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3003)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3002)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3002)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1318)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3194)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1041)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2406)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$9(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$8(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:479)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriterV2.runCommand(DataFrameWriterV2.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriterV2.append(DataFrameWriterV2.scala:150)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:244)
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
    at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy62.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1(ForeachBatchSink.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1$adapted(ForeachBatchSink.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$9(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$8(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:311)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password

